On JD Jackson's derivation of Matrix Representations of Lorentz Tranformations
Jackson derives the ordinary rotation matrix for a rotation through angle $ \omega$ about the $z$ axis (eq.11.96) via the exponential map of the Lorentz group:
$$A=e^{-\vec{\omega}\cdot\vec S-\vec \zeta\cdot\vec K},$$
where $ A$ is the Lorentz group element, $\vec K$ and $\vec S$ "vectors of generator matrices" and $\vec\omega$ and $\vec\zeta$ constant vectors which specify the parameters of the continuous group. For the simple case of $\vec \zeta=0$ and $\vec \omega = \omega\hat\epsilon_3$, Jackson gets that $A$ is the usual rotation matrix. How does one get this result from the exponential map:
$$A=e^{-\omega S_3}.$$
Here the generator $S_3$ is real and there is no factor of $i$ in the exponent, thus how does one go from the power series representation of the matrix exponential to the sines and cosines in the ordinary rotation matrix?

The "sines and cosines" comes from the algebraic properties of the generator.
The Lie algebra of the rotation group $SO(3)$ is given (as can be checked by differentiating the $SO(3)$ condition $R R^T=I$), by the set of skew-symmetric $3\times 3$ matrices. Writing this set as $$ \mathfrak{so}(3)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a &b\\ -a &0&c\\-b&-c & 0 \end{pmatrix} ;\, a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^3 \right\}$$
you can easily pick off the $3$ generators of rotations. In particular, $\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ is the generator of rotations about the $z$ axis. Notice that is basically a matrix with an "$i$" in the upper left corner (since the $2\times2$ matrix in the upper left corner squares to minus the identity; this is where your "missing $i$" was).
If you diagonalize this matrix, you will recognize that it has eigenvalues $0$ and $\pm i$. It is not then so surprising that its exponentiation, $$e^{\omega K_3}=\begin{pmatrix} \cos \omega &\sin \omega & 0\\-\sin \omega & \cos \omega &0 \\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
is precisely a rotation about the $z$ axis.
In short, it is in the algebraic properties of such generators, by virtue of their skew-symmetry, that the " $i$ character" of the rotations is hiding.

Thanks, is it possible to realize the result working from the power series expansion of the matrix exponential?

@AlbertusMagnus Yeah, just work out the powers of the generator, it's not too hard
